# Why is BiConsumer allowed to be assigned with a function that only accepts a single parameter?

Tags: lambda, java-8

Say, for the following example:

```
public class MyConsumer {
    public void accept(int i) {}
    public static void biAccept(MyConsumer mc, int i) {}
}

public class BiConsumerDemo {

    public void accept(int i) { }
    public static void biAccept(MyConsumer mc, int i) { }

    private void testBiConsume() {
        BiConsumer<MyConsumer, Integer> accumulator = (x, y) -> {}; // no problem, method accepts 2 parameters
        accumulator = MyConsumer::accept; // accepts only one parameter and yet is treated as BiConsumer
        accumulator = MyConsumer::biAccept; // needed to be static
        accumulator = BiConsumerDemo::accept; // compilation error, only accepts single parameter
    }
}
```

Why is that the variable `accumulator`, which is a `BiConsumer` that requires a function to accept 2 parameters, can be assigned with `MyConsumer::accept` when that method only accepts only a single parameter?

What is the principle behind this language design in Java? If there's a term for it, what is it?

Comment: also see [Java 8 Method Reference: How to Use it](https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`MyConsumer::accept` is a method reference to an instance method of `MyConsumer` class that has a single argument of type `int`. The `MyConsumer` instance on which the method is called is considered an implicit argument of the method reference.

Therefore:

```
accumulator = MyConsumer::accept;
```

is equivalent to:

```
accumulator = (MyConsumer m,Integer i) -> m.accept(i);
```

> given a targeted function type with **n parameters**, a set of potentially applicable methods is identified:
>
> - If the method reference expression has the form ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier, the potentially applicable methods are the member methods of the type to search that have an appropriate name (given by Identifier), accessibility, arity **(n or n-1)**, and type argument arity (derived from [TypeArguments]), as specified in §15.12.2.1.
>
>   **Two different arities, n and n-1, are considered, to account for the possibility that this form refers to either a static method or an instance method**.

(from [15.13.1. Compile-Time Declaration of a Method Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1) )

In your case the target function type is `BiConsumer`, which has 2 parameters. Therefore any methods of the `MyConsumer` class matching the name `accept` and having 2 or 1 parameters are considered.

Both static methods having 2 parameters and instance methods having 1 parameter can match the target function type.